# SQL - Break down compensation time span fpr employees by year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to be able to have start and end dates per year on employees.  At least one row per year and where the compensation changes within the year, I need multiple rows that span each year.  I'll need to pro-rate any changes, etc. Below is some code, I can get the timespan start and stop but need to include rows for the year in-between.

Example: John - should have years 2011 - 2019 (for 2011 - start date 12/14 and end date 12/31) and include the appropriate salary for each year thereafter.  Any help is appreciated!!!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EMPLOYEE]
(
    [EMPID] [VARCHAR](15) NULL,
    [NAME] [VARCHAR](15) NULL,
    [FIRST_HIRE_DATE] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [HIRE_DT] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [TERM_DT] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EMPLOYEE] 
VALUES ('100123', 'John', '2015-12-14 00:00:00.000', '2015-12-14 00:00:00.000', NULL),
       ('100124', 'Jane', '2015-02-09 00:00:00.000', '2015-02-09 00:00:00.000', '2019-11-01 00:00:00.000');

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EMPLOYEE_CHANGES]
(
    [EMPID] [VARCHAR](15) NULL,
    [NAME] [VARCHAR](15) NULL,
    [SALARY_EFFECTIVE_DATE] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [CHANGE_REASON] [VARCHAR](25) NULL,
    [ANNUAL_SALARY] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EMPLOYEE_CHANGES] 
VALUES ('100123', 'John', '2011-12-14 00:00:00.000', 'NewHire', 'Active', 100000.00),
       ('100123', 'John', '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'AnnualIncrease', 'Active', 110000.00),
       ('100124', 'Jane', '2015-02-09 00:00:00.000', 'NewHire', 'Active', 200000.00),
       ('100124', 'Jane', '2016-02-13 00:00:00.000', 'AnnualIncrease', 'Active', 215000.00),
       ('100124', 'Jane', '2017-02-11 00:00:00.000', 'AnnualIncrease', 'Active', 225000.00),
       ('100124', 'Jane', '2019-02-09 00:00:00.000', 'Resignation', 'Terminated', 225000.00)

SELECT 
    e.empid, e.name,
    e.FIRST_HIRE_DATE, e.HIRE_DT, e.TERM_DT, 
    NULL AS YEAR, c.ANNUAL_SALARY, SALARY_EFFECTIVE_DATE AS SalaryEffStartDt,
    LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, -1, SALARY_EFFECTIVE_DATE), 1, e.TERM_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY c.empid ORDER BY c.SALARY_EFFECTIVE_DATE) SalaryEffEndDt
INTO
    #test
FROM
    employee e
JOIN
    EMPLOYEE_CHANGES c ON c.empid = e.EMPID
ORDER BY 
    empid, SalaryEffStartDt
```

Comment: Stop and think first. HIRE_DT is a DATE, not a datetime. So start using the correct datatypes. Same thing for SALARY_EFFECTIVE_DATE. All of your columns are nullable? Nope. No primary or foreign keys? Nope. Start over. Explain why you need to use <select ... into ...>. You want at least 1 row in your resultset for every year within a period of interest? You will need to generate those boundaries outside of the rows you currently have. How to do that? A shortened form of a calendar table will do that - search the internet.

Comment: I imagine that the tables defined above are just for illustrative purposes so we can quickly and easily spin up our own local example - is the exact type of the `HIRE_DT` column or the nullability of the columns going to affect the answer to [irishgirl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12397870/irishgirl)s question? I wouldn't think so...

Comment: I don't know how you could do this in a single query.  A Calendar table, and a cursor of cursors (for each Employee) inserting into a temp table, is how I would approach it.